# how do Buffered Reader and string builder work?

Tags: java, android

I am using this code to read a file:

```
try {
    InputStreamReader inputStreamReader = new  InputStreamReader(openFileInput(TEXTFILE));
    BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(inputStreamReader);
    StringBuilder stringbuilder = new StringBuilder();
    String string=bufferedReader.readLine();
    while (string!=null){
        stringbuilder.append(string);
        string=bufferedReader.readLine();
    }
    EditText.setText(stringbuilder.toString());
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Why is it needed to use while for stringbuilder?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out.
When using `bufferedReader.readLine();` ,the `readLine()` reads the first "available" line in bufferedReader Object and then That line becomes unavailable.
So the next time `readLine()` is used,It will read the next line.

So we use `while` to make it continue reading until there is no available line.

using `StringBuilder` , we can "append" those lines in one String.

Answer (score 0):

When you have to build a string, you should automaticaly use a StringBuilder. That is better in terms of resource saving. Because concatenation creates a new instance of String to stock the result. For example `SResult = S1 + S2`.So `sResult` is a new string.

When it comes to use a String builder, You create one single instance of String that is the result. So in terms of created instances, you have `s1+s2+s3+...+sN+sResult` instances instead of having new instances multiplied by the number of times you concatenate.

Using a BufferedReader, you will iterate on lines of the file. the `readline();` call will simply return the next line to read until the `BufferedReader` reaches the end of the file. Saying that the method `readLine();` will read untill the next line feed character `'\n'` is more accurate.

[MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-be/library/system.io.streamreader.readline%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) :
*A line is defined as a sequence of characters followed by a line feed ("\n"), a carriage return ("\r"), or a carriage return immediately followed by a line feed ("\r\n"). The string that is returned does not contain the terminating carriage return or line feed. The returned value is null if the end of the input stream is reached.*

You must use a `try-with-resource` to manipulate streams since Java 7. Because in your case, you don't close it at the end. That's not the proper way to do. Your way provides issues when accessing your file by your OS navigator for instance even you close your java application. Your file could still be open if it's not closed so `try-with-resource block` does the work for you.
See: [try-with-resource](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html)